# How do I print i and j only once per iteration in Python

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I am trying to print i and j once such that instead of printing:
00,01,02,03,04,05,06....10,11,12

The output should be:00,11,22,33.....

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
for i in range(10):
  for j in range(10):
    print(str(i)+str(j))
    j+=1
  i+=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for **`zip()`** :

```
for i, j in zip(range(10), range(10)):
    print(i, j)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(10):
  for j in range(10):
     if i == j:
        print(str(i)+str(j))
```